# jquery: how to prevent navigation (link/submit)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to convert my website to Single Page Application. 
What I try to do is to capture navigation process: 
ex:

```
<a href="myData.php">Change My Data</a>
```

When user click "Change My Data" link (or any other link), I want to capture that click and load the content (myData.php) with ajax and display it into my mainContent div.

```
<div id="mainContent"></div>
```

Problem is : I cannot prevent the click: I tried with and no success:

```
$( window ).unload(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  return "Handler for .unload() called.";
});
```

**Any idea how to prevent the default click (and then the form POST and GET), and get the target url so I can load it through ajax and display into my div content ?**

Comment: I might be missing something but would you not put the jQuery on the anchor e.g. $('a').on('click', function(){//do ajax and use return false;});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than targetting the `unload` method you could target anchor elements themselves. For example:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#mainContent").load($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

This is very generic though and would include targetting external application links. Therefore I suggest flagging existing anchors with a `data` attribute to ensure you're only converting specific links into AJAX calls:

```
<a href="myData.php" data-loadajax="true">Change My Data</a>

$("a").click(function(e){
    if ($(this).data("loadajax")){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#mainContent").load($(this).attr("href") + " #mainContent");
    }
});
```